# Flutter - Unable to access photo gallery in iOS device with flle picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Please, is anyone able to help me to understand why in iOS I can access only iCloud files? I need users to be able to access files (videos and images) from the device gallery. I am not sure if it a permission issue but in the info.plist files I've this:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allows you to take a picture</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allows you to record a voice</string>
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allows you to choose a music</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allows you to choose a picture</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

In the Podfile, I have also this:

target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!

and below my code to pick video, up to 5 files, selected one by one...

```
List<Files> _selectedFiles = [];

pickVideos() async {
if (_selectedFiles.length >= 5) {
  Toast.show(t.maximumallowedsizehint, context);
  return;
}
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  // allowCompression: true,
  allowMultiple: true,
  withData: false,
  allowedExtensions: ['mp4'],
);
if (mounted) {
  if (result != null) {
    PlatformFile file = result.files.first;

    print(file.name);
    //print(file.bytes);
    print(file.size);
    print(file.extension);
    print(file.path);
    if (file.size > (1024 * 100)) {
      Toast.show(t.maximumuploadsizehint, context);
      return;
    }

    final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(file.path);
    print("video absolute path " + filePath);
    _selectedFiles.add(new Files(
        link: filePath,
        type: "video",
        filetype: file.extension,
        length: file.size,
        thumbnail: "null"));
    //genThumbnailFile(_selectedFiles.length - 1);
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: allowedExtensions: ['mp4', 'jpg'],  have you tried with this ?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I actually don't want to do that because I have another method to pick specific images formats... but thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've contacted the package owner (Miguel Ruivo) and he was very kind to answer me to provide the solution.

instead of using FileType.custom

```
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.custom);
```

use FileType.media:

```
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.media);
```

That solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I read the source code and I saw that it doesn't allow to use FileType. custom with allowedExtensions :
[image]